# Add bbcode [b], [i], [code], etc. to WordPress via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys, first off I played around with shortcodes, but they aren't working. I might have a some conflict (tried for hours to find it) but for now, it's not an option. But the following works in allowing my commenters to use the [img] tags in their comments (which get replaced to the html  equivalents) and I'd like to expand on it.

**Please no plugins!**

What I'd like to do is amend the following bit of code to allow [b], [i], and [code] (both lower and upper case entries) to spit out the html equivalents so my comments can just use the standard bbcodes when they comment, very much how the current function works:

```
function embed_images($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/\[img=?\]*(.*?)(\[\/img)?\]/ei', '"<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"" . basename("$1") . "\" />"', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('comment_text', 'embed_images');
```

I've tried and tried but can't get it to work. Any coding help would be greatly appreciate. Thanks guys.

Edit: Okay guys, got it working. Does this look okay? I mean it works, but how is the code... decent?

```
function embed_bold($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/\[b]*(.*?)(\[\/b)?\]/ei', '"<strong>$1</strong>"', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('comment_text', 'embed_bold');
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once wrote a blog post about using regex for bbcodes. Most recommend using a PHP extension specifically built for BBCodes however. Here is the article:

http://www.spotlesswebdesign.com/blog.php?id=12

```
/\[b](.+?)\[\/b]/i
```

replace with

```
'<strong>$1</strong>'
```

Comment: I've seen something like that before, but how to implement it into WordPress?

Comment: @Lokheed just add the desired expressions and repacements into the preg_replace() found in your example code i think

Comment: I got it working. Not the same as yours, but it works. How does the code look to you? Decent, or just an abomination?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know from other another non-related post here that "ie" adds case insensitivity, and I need that. Some people may put [B] while others may put [b]. But I tried using "/[b](.+?)[\/b]/" and it doesn't work. Again, not a coder, but I'm pretty sure WordPress needs the extras. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: the sit took some slashes out of the comment. try the edit above.

Comment: The new code works, but surrounds the content in quotes (e.g., "bold text")... But adding an 'e' before the 'i' makes it work as it should. Thanks for the update :)

Comment: @Lokheed the "e" modifier makes your preg_replace evaluate the replacement text as if it were code. this is very dangerous, especially mixed with user submitted content. do not use the "e". all you need to do is take the double quotes out of your replacement string. see above edits for new replacement string.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the security tip; quickly modified. And thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay dqhendricks, based on your coding convention, I've merged all bbcodes into one function. Any serious coding violations, or does it look good?

```
//add bbcode tags
function embed_bbcode($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/\[img](.+?)\[\/img]/ei', '"<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"" . basename("$1") . "\" />"', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/\[b](.+?)\[\/b]/ei', '"<strong>$1</strong>"', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/\[i](.+?)\[\/i]/ei', '"<em>$1</em>"', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/\[code](.+?)\[\/code]/ei', '"<code>$1</code>"', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/\[quote](.+?)\[\/quote]/ei', '"<blockquote>$1</blockquote>"', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('comment_text', 'embed_bbcode');
```

Thanks again for all your help.